# Javascript- Adding click event to dynamically generated cell of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

`addEventListener()` not working ?

```
var mytable = document.getElementById('GridTable');

for (var r = 0; r <rows; r++) 
{
    var row = mytable.insertRow(r);
    for (var c = 0; c <cols; c++)
    {

        var cell=row.insertCell(c);
        cell.id='td'+nn;
        //alert(cell.id);
        cell.innerHTML='&nbsp';
        cell.className="dynamic";
        cell.addEventListener("click", function() {bcolor1('red',cell.id);});
        nn++;
    }

}
```

Comment: bcolor1 ?..... where is it?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code(with your HTML). The function `bcolor1('red',cell.id)` is missing.

Comment: you've tagged jquery but have none in your example, are you using jquery?

Comment: bcolor1('red',cell.id); is my function which apply background color to clicked cell.    When I try to execute this code and click on any cell it is applying red color to only last cell of table, am totally confused  plz help me ......

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation to achieve this.

With `Javascript`, you can do it this way:

```
document.querySelector('element').addEventListener('click', function(event) {      
    // on click action here..
});
```

With `jQuery`, you can do it this way:

```
$(document).on("click", "element", function(){
  // on click action here..
});
```

Learn more: [Understanding Event Delegation | jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on()` function to achieve event delegation.

This way, you can select every dynamicaly added element with class `.dynamic`

```
$(document).on('click', '.dynamic', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.css({'background-color': 'red'});
    // do your stuff here ..
});
```

Comment: informative purpose: double semicolon, syntax, line 2: `var that = $(this;);` should be `var that = $(this);`

Answer (score 0):

I got the following solution and it is working fine .

```
 var mytable = document.getElementById('GridTable');
 for (var r = 0; r <trow; r++) 
    {
        temp=noc;
        var row = mytable.insertRow(r);
        for (var c = 0; c <tcol; c++)
        {
            cell=row.insertCell(c);
            cell.id='td'+temp;
            cell.style.width =cwidth;
            cell.style.height =cheight;
            //alert(cell.id);
            //cell.innerHTML='&nbsp;';
            cell.className="dynamic";

            with ({ n: cell.id }) 
            {
                cell.onclick = function()
                {
                        bcolor1('red',n);
                };
                cell.onmousemove=function()
                {
                    bcolor('red',n);
                }   
            }                                                         
            temp++;
        }
        noc=noc-tcol;
    }
```